# Recuperar arquivo .gz corrompido

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, linux

tenho um arquivo em .gz que está corrompido.

Existe a possibilidade de extrair os dados desse arquivo? Mesmo que seja parcialmente?

Esse arquivo é um dump de banco de dados sql.

Valeu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sim, é possível tentar recuperar um arquivo .gz, mas espere ter grandes perdas de dados do meio dele.

Primeiro, faça uma cópia do arquivo e trabalhe só com a cópia.

Faça um

```
gunzip  < arquivo_com_erro.gz > arquivo_saida
```

E o seu arquivo saida terá tudo que foi possível recuperar até a primeira falha.

Para recuperar o que está depois da falha, um método é compilando o programa gzip com algumas linhas a mais de código. Para isto, sugiro seguir o recomendado em http://www.gzip.org/recover.txt (em ingles, e já adianto que levará tempo e não será fácil)

Outra solução: consulte as ferramentas disponíveis em http://www.urbanophile.com/arenn/coding/gzrt/gzrt.html

Comment: Isso funcionou e eu consegui abrir o arquivo ".sql" que estava dentro dele.
Apareceram vários caracteres desconhecidos (que eu acredito ser da parte corrompida).
Vou fazer o up da base agora (que tem mais 1,4GB) e ver no que dá. 
Obrigado pela ajuda.